# How to use varying grid spacing on the same axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to use more than one grid steps on the x axis in matplotlib.
For example, my x axis starts from 0.1 to 1.0 with step 0.1, and continues from 1 to 10 with step 1, and further continues from 10 to 100 with step 10.
I want these data to look uniformly spaced, so I would not use log scale in this axis.
I can of course manually set the ticks, but it is cumbersome and I wish there is a better way to do it.

Comment: If you want a completely arbitrary, custom grid spacing... you're going to have to define it manually.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes, it seems difficult and maybe I really need to do it manually. But it is not completely arbitrary. For every order of magnitude, it is even spaced. I have searched around, but matplotlib does not seem to provide this functionality.